# a href links not showing url aliases

Tags: path-aliases, redirection

I am using redirect module with Drupal 8 latest version. It is working fine when we open any node in url, it converts node to the path alias. But issue is with a href links. **When we hover on any "a" link it is showing the node number not the path alias** set for that node. After click on it is displaying again path alias in the url bar.

How we can display the alias on hovering any "a" href link ?

Comment: Please provide details on how you're generating/print link.

Comment: i am adding links directly in content editor (CKEditor) 
 for e.g. <a class="btn" href="[site:url]/node/475" >Link to page</a>

Comment: In drupal 7 we had Pathologic (https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) module which handled this linking issue. But for drupal 8 haven't found anything helpful. 
Thanks in advance @Yogesh for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Linkit](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit). This will allow you to select internal links inside CKEditor and will convert them to aliases.

> Linkit provides an easy interface for internal and external linking with wysiwyg editors by using an autocomplete field. Linkit has by default support for nodes, users, taxonomy terms, files, comments and basic support for all types of entities that defines a canonical link template.

[image: link widget]

Comment: I have already checked this and this will help me only to put new links. But we have around 500 pages already created in our website and we have used "[site:url]/node/475" for all the the internal links. 
So can suggest any module or configuration changes which will directly change all this links to url alias.